# Get fully qualified class name of an object in Python

Tags: python, python-datamodel

For logging purposes I want to retrieve the fully qualified class name of a Python object. (With fully qualified I mean the class name including the package and module name.)

I know about `x.__class__.__name__`, but is there a simple method to get the package and module?

Answer (score 219, accepted):

With the following program

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import foo

def fullname(o):
    klass = o.__class__
    module = klass.__module__
    if module == 'builtins':
        return klass.__qualname__ # avoid outputs like 'builtins.str'
    return module + '.' + klass.__qualname__

bar = foo.Bar()
print(fullname(bar))
```

and `Bar` defined as

```py
class Bar(object):
  def __init__(self, v=42):
    self.val = v
```

the output is

```
$ ./prog.py
foo.Bar
```

If you're still stuck on Python 2, you'll have to use `__name__` instead of `__qualname__`, which is less informative for nested classes - a class `Bar` nested in a class `Foo` will show up as `Bar` instead of `Foo.Bar`:

```
def fullname(o):
    klass = o.__class__
    module = klass.__module__
    if module == '__builtin__':
        return klass.__name__ # avoid outputs like '__builtin__.str'
    return module + '.' + klass.__name__
```

Comment: This appears to return the module where bar was defined, not where Bar was defined. If the purpose of logging is to know exactly what kind of object it was, then this doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Is `o.__class__.__module__` ever different from `o.__module__`?

Comment: larsks: yes it is, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271112/obtaining-module-name-x-module-vs-x-class-module

Comment: I strongly recomend `".".join([o.__module__, o.__name__])` for Python3

Comment: Doesn't work sometimes: `AttributeError: 'AttributeError' object has no attribute '__module__'`

Answer (score 59):

The provided answers don't deal with nested classes.

Since Python 3.3 ([PEP 3155](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3155)), you can use `__qualname__` of the class instead of the `__name__`. Otherwise, a class like

```
class Foo:
    class Bar: # this one
        pass
```

will show up as just `Bar` instead of `Foo.Bar`.

(You'll still need to attach the `__module__` to the qualname separately - `__qualname__` is not intended to include module names.)

Comment: If you use https://github.com/wbolster/qualname you can get a __qualname__ equivalent on older versions.

Comment: I.e. `Type.__module__ + '.' + Type.__qualname__`.

Comment: With Python 3.6, this only gives me the class name. It doesn't include the module.

Comment: @jpmc26 In Python 3.7, `__qualname__` still only resolves to the class name

Answer (score 33):

Here's one based on Greg Bacon's excellent answer, but with a couple of extra checks:

`__module__` can be `None` (according to the docs), and also for a type like `str` it can be `__builtin__` (which you might not want appearing in logs or whatever).  The following checks for both those possibilities:

```
def fullname(o):
    module = o.__class__.__module__
    if module is None or module == str.__class__.__module__:
        return o.__class__.__name__
    return module + '.' + o.__class__.__name__
```

(There might be a better way to check for `__builtin__`.  The above just relies on the fact that str is always available, and its module is always `__builtin__`)

Comment: To save others the effort of comparing the two answers: the code in Greg Bacon's answer is now identical to the code in this one, other than that Greg added a pointless else statement and some code comments.  MB is the real hero.

Comment: `str.__class__.__module__` evaluates to `'builtins'`, so would there be anything wrong with `if module is None or module == 'builtins'`?

Comment: The docs say `__module__` can be `None` *for functions*, but for classes, if Python can't determine a module when creating a type, the `__module__` attribute just won't exist at all - you'll get an AttributeError if you try to access it. `__module__` can also be manually set to arbitrary objects.

Comment: Checking `module is None` thus doesn't add any meaningful safety. Handling `AttributeError` and checking the type would be more useful, though still unlikely to matter.

Comment: Also, if you're that paranoid about `__module__`, you have to be equally paranoid about `__class__`, which is not actually guaranteed to be an object's class. It might not even be a class at all, for example if a class has a `__getattribute__` override that doesn't special-case `__class__`.

Answer (score 30):

For python3.7 I use:

```py
".".join([obj.__module__, obj.__name__])
```

Getting:

```
package.subpackage.ClassName
```

Comment: note that `obj` must be a class rather than an object instance.

Answer (score 21):

Consider using the `inspect` module which has functions like `getmodule` which might be what are looking for:

```
>>>import inspect
>>>import xml.etree.ElementTree
>>>et = xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree()
>>>inspect.getmodule(et)
<module 'xml.etree.ElementTree' from 
        'D:\tools\python2.5.2\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.pyc'>
```

Comment: `inspect.getmodule()` returns **module objects** – not **fully qualified class names.** In fact, the `inspect` module provides no functionality whatsoever that would actually address this question. This answer is a non-answer. `</facepalm>`

Comment: Should be `<facepalm/>`

Comment: Helpful. Except for classes defined in the `builtins` module, the fully qualified name of a class might typically represent the class' module name suffixed with the `cls.__name__`, and now we have a function for determining if the class is defined in the `builtins` module, e.g that module returned by `inspect.getmodule(object)`. Accessing the `module` class in itself might seem to be a bit more challenging, except by a similar indirection?

Answer (score 13):

Some people (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/16763814/5766934) arguing that `__qualname__` is better than `__name__`.
Here is an example that shows the difference:

```
$ cat dummy.py 
class One:
    class Two:
        pass

$ python3.6
>>> import dummy
>>> print(dummy.One)
<class 'dummy.One'>
>>> print(dummy.One.Two)
<class 'dummy.One.Two'>
>>> def full_name_with_name(klass):
...     return f'{klass.__module__}.{klass.__name__}'
>>> def full_name_with_qualname(klass):
...     return f'{klass.__module__}.{klass.__qualname__}'
>>> print(full_name_with_name(dummy.One))  # Correct
dummy.One
>>> print(full_name_with_name(dummy.One.Two))  # Wrong
dummy.Two
>>> print(full_name_with_qualname(dummy.One))  # Correct
dummy.One
>>> print(full_name_with_qualname(dummy.One.Two))  # Correct
dummy.One.Two
```

Note, it also works correctly for builtins:

```
>>> print(full_name_with_qualname(print))
builtins.print
>>> import builtins
>>> builtins.print
<built-in function print>
```

Answer (score 11):

`__module__` would do the trick.

Try:

```
>>> import re
>>> print re.compile.__module__
re
```

[This site](http://www.swaroopch.com/notes/Python_en:Modules) suggests that `__package__` might work for Python 3.0; However, the examples given there won't work under my Python 2.5.2 console.

Comment: That does the trick, thanks!

For the fully qualified name I will use

`"%s.%s" % (x.__class__.__module__, x.__class__.__name__)`

Answer (score 7):

This is a hack but I'm supporting 2.6 and just need something simple:

```
>>> from logging.handlers import MemoryHandler as MH
>>> str(MH).split("'")[1]

'logging.handlers.MemoryHandler'
```

Comment: This depends on the `__repr__()` implementation in the checked class (**and** on `__str__()` not being overriden). Useless in most cases.

Answer (score 5):

Bellow is just an improvement of Greg Bacon's answer, tested for class, instance, method, function, both builtin and user defined.

```py
def fullname(o):
    try:
        # if o is a class or function, get module directly
        module = o.__module__
    except AttributeError:
        # then get module from o's class
        module = o.__class__.__module__
    try:
        # if o is a class or function, get name directly
        name = o.__qualname__
    except AttributeError:
        # then get o's class name
        name = o.__class__.__qualname__
    # if o is a method of builtin class, then module will be None
    if module == 'builtins' or module is None:
        return name
    return module + '.' + name
```

Comment: How can we get the full name of (global) variables and Properties?

Answer (score 3):

Since the interest of this topic is to get fully qualified names, here is a pitfall that occurs when using relative imports along with the main module existing in the same package. E.g., with the below module setup:

```
$ cat /tmp/fqname/foo/__init__.py
$ cat /tmp/fqname/foo/bar.py
from baz import Baz
print Baz.__module__
$ cat /tmp/fqname/foo/baz.py
class Baz: pass
$ cat /tmp/fqname/main.py
import foo.bar
from foo.baz import Baz
print Baz.__module__
$ cat /tmp/fqname/foo/hum.py
import bar
import foo.bar
```

Here is the output showing the result of importing the same module differently:

```
$ export PYTHONPATH=/tmp/fqname
$ python /tmp/fqname/main.py
foo.baz
foo.baz
$ python /tmp/fqname/foo/bar.py
baz
$ python /tmp/fqname/foo/hum.py
baz
foo.baz
```

When hum imports bar using relative path, bar sees `Baz.__module__` as just "baz", but in the second import that uses full name, bar sees the same as "foo.baz".

If you are persisting the fully-qualified names somewhere, it is better to avoid relative imports for those classes.

Answer (score 2):

This is an adaption of the answers by [Greg Bacon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2020083/) and [MB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13653312/) to use the qualified class name. Note that the question did ask for the qualified class name. It was tested with Python 3.8.

```py
def fullname(obj: object) -> str:
    """Return the full name of the given object using its module and qualified class names."""
    # Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66508248/
    module_name, class_name = obj.__class__.__module__, obj.__class__.__qualname__
    if module_name in (None, str.__class__.__module__):
        return class_name
    return module_name + "." + class_name
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution is:

```
def fullname(obj) -> str:
    if type(obj).__qualname__ != "type":
        # obj is instance
        return ".".join(
            [
                obj.__class__.__module__,
                obj.__class__.__qualname__,
            ]
        )
    # obj is not instance
    return ".".join([obj.__module__, obj.__qualname__])
 
 # not instance
 >>> print(fullname(datetime))
 "datetime.datetime"
 # instance
 >>> print(fullname(datetime.now())
 "datetime.datetime"
 # instance
 >>> print(fullname(3))
 "builtins.int"
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers here worked for me. In my case, I was using Python 2.7 and knew that I would only be working with newstyle `object` classes.

```
def get_qualified_python_name_from_class(model):
    c = model.__class__.__mro__[0]
    name = c.__module__ + "." + c.__name__
    return name
```