# In Python, given a class, how can I find what module it came from?

Tags: python

When using the interactive shell in Spyder, for instance, all sorts of classes are in the global namespace, so it would be nice to be able to interactively find what module the class comes from.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027848/getting-corresponding-module-from-function has a code example of doing this.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020014/get-fully-qualified-class-name-of-an-object-in-python, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271112/obtaining-module-name-x-module-vs-x-class-module, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12569452/how-to-identify-numpy-types-in-python.

Comment: You're right, it seems like there are several similar answers.  Somehow in searching using the wording of my question, I did not find those.  Perhaps for that small reason this question still has some value.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is buried in one of the responses to the [hidden features of Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python/3242895#3242895) question:

> You can ask any object which module it came from by looking at its
>   `__module__` property. This is useful, for example, if you're
>   experimenting at the command line and have imported a lot of things.
>
> Along the same lines, you can ask a module where it came from by
>   looking at its `__file__` property. This is useful when debugging path
>   issues.