# Cases where a.__module__ differs from a.__class__.__module__

Tags: python, class, module, python-module

When `a` is a `Class`, `a.__module__` may be different from `a.__class__.__module__`.
[Obtaining module name: x.__module__ vs x.__class__.__module__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271112/obtaining-module-name-x-module-vs-x-class-module)

**Is there any other case where they may be different**

Comment: Well, `__module__` is writable, from which a rather trivial case follows.

Comment: @Norrius - Ok... Any other?