# Fully qualified class name in Jython

Tags: python, jython, classname

Supposing some.module.MyClass is a Java class, if it is imported in Jython 2.1, its fully qualified class name can be got like this:

```
from some.module import MyClass
print MyClass.__name__
```

then "some.module.MyClass" was printed.

Now, the same code in Jython 2.5 prints "MyClass" only.

To get the complete name in Jython 2.5, I've found the following:

```
print MyClass.name
```

It prints "some.module.MyClass" (I guess java.lang.Class.getName() is called).

The problem is if MyClass has a getName method. Then the above fails.

The solution I've found is to call

```
print MyClass.__module__ + "." + MyClass.__name__
```

but it is a lot more wordy.

If anyone knows a simpler way (like the original __name__), it would be welcome.

**Note:** I already know the full class name (in fact I have imported it). I want it this way to detect changes in case the class is renamed or moved. For example:

```
className = "some.module.MyClass"   # needs to be changed manually if MyClass is moved
```

opposed to

```
className = MyClass.name   # no need to be changed if MyClass is moved
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get fully qualified class name of an object in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020014/get-fully-qualified-class-name-of-an-object-in-python)

Comment: @katrielalex Not a duplicate -- there might be an always-works JVM-y way of doing it, since `MyClass.name` works some of the time, and they accepted answer to that question is mentioned in this one as too wordy.

Comment: @agf: Fair enough; ideally the OP could edit to make it clear that they are looking for a JVM-specific method and that they know about the previous question.

Comment: Yes, I know the previous post. In this case, I have a class object, not an instance of the class. I don't mind if the way to get the complete class name is a JVM specific method or a Jython hook.

Answer (score 0):

The following works:

```
print MyClass.canonicalName
```

It would print "some.module.MyClass" as expected.

In this case, java.lang.Class.getCanonicalName is called.

It is less likely that an arbitrary class will have a method called getCanonicalName() than getName(), so in principle it is more reliable than

```
print MyClass.name
```

Nevertheless, a pure Jython *simple* way (if existing) would also be appreciated.