# Python Unique Method Identifier

Tags: python, memcached

I'm trying to cache a python method's output, so for the cache key I'm using hash(method) + the serialized args. I'm using a single memcached server for multiple worker machines.

The problem is, hash(method) has proven inconsistent across these worker machines and processes.

```
class Foo(object):
    def bar():
       pass

x = Foo()
hash(x.bar) #was inconsistent across machines/processes
```

id() won't work because that's a memory location and thus works on only one machine.

Thanks!

Comment: @delnan: Oh, we're hashing functions... Nvm

Comment: @NiklasB. what do you recommend I take the MD5 hash of? The function takes a string input...

Comment: djs22: Arguments and some kind of fully-qualified function name. This is a solved problem already, though, just look at the links provided in the second answer.

Comment: Maybe either hashing the fully qualified name (as linked in a comment below) or using the results of inspect.getsource() would suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at one the the avialable memcached decorators?

- http://blog.isotoma.com/2009/09/of-python-memcached-and-decorators-easy-peasy-function-caching/
- http://pypi.python.org/pypi/memorised/1.0.2
- https://github.com/1stvamp/memorised
- http://www.zieglergasse.at/blog/2011/python/memcached-decorator-for-python/

Comment: Thanks dgorissen! I ended up using the code from 1stvamp's github as a base to write properly implemented fully qualified function names.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the name of the function instead, like `x.foo.__name__`.

Comment: Yes but what about functions with the same name in different classes/modules?

Comment: @djs22: Obviously you should include the module/class name too in that case.

Comment: Don't give functions the same name if you'll be hashing them based on their names?

Comment: @djs22: add the class/module/package name: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020014/get-fully-qualified-class-name-of-an-object-in-python

Comment: Even then it's prone to causing problems, especially with smarter code (any kind of metaprogramming, for instance). It's also arguably dirty to use such a decidedly collision-prone key.

Comment: @NiklasB., in the situation I'm using this (inside a decorator), it's not easy to access the module/class name. I used the code linked to in the accepted answer to learn how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Setup a name mangling function that will take the class name and method name to create a string and then take the hash for the string. For example let x be the method then

```
def method_hash(x):
    return hash("{0}.{1}".format(x.__objclass__.__name__, x.__name__))
```

This assumes that the method is from the class and not a specific object. If from the object then `x.__self__.__name__` could be used instead.

Comment: The `__class__` of functions is `<class 'function'>`, at least in 3.x (it *may* work in 2.x with its "unbound methods" but I wouldn't bet on it).

Comment: @delnan Thanks for catching my error on `__class__`, I edited my answer to handle it.

Comment: A good answer, but due to reason's not specified in the original question (I need to generate this unique identifier within a decorator), it's not always easy to tell if you're in a class/object/or just module.