# How to get the name of an exception that was caught in Python?

Tags: python, exception

How can I get the name of an exception that was raised in Python?

e.g.,

```
try:
    foo = bar
except Exception as exception:
    name_of_exception = ???
    assert name_of_exception == 'NameError'
    print "Failed with exception [%s]" % name_of_exception
```

For example, I am catching multiple (or all) exceptions, and want to print the name of the exception in an error message.

Comment: *Why* do you think you need this? Why not catch a more concrete exception (e.g. `except NameError:`) to begin with?

Comment: I have a couple scenarios where I want to catch all exceptions (or a list of them), and want to print out the name of the exception in an error message.

Comment: You might want to check out the standard library's [`traceback`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html) module, which has functions that do some nice formatting of exceptions and tracebacks.

Comment: @delnan this  situation arises when you are testing if a function is raising an exception as programmed

Comment: I needed something like this to DRY up some code: several exceptions can be raised by the method I'm calling, each are handled with their own `except` statement, but the log entry is very similar in each case.

Answer (score 389, accepted):

Here are a few different ways to get the name of the class of the exception:

1. `type(exception).__name__`
2. `exception.__class__.__name__`
3. `exception.__class__.__qualname__`

e.g.,

```
try:
    foo = bar
except Exception as exception:
    assert type(exception).__name__ == 'NameError'
    assert exception.__class__.__name__ == 'NameError'
    assert exception.__class__.__qualname__ == 'NameError'
```

Comment: when you raise `raise socket.timeout` you only get the name: `timeout`

Comment: Is there a way to get the `traceback(most recent call last) : ...` ?

Answer (score 24):

If you want the **fully qualified class name** (e.g. `sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError` instead of just `IntegrityError`), you can use the function below, which I took from [MB's awesome answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13653312/5405967) to another question (I just renamed some variables to suit my tastes):

```
def get_full_class_name(obj):
    module = obj.__class__.__module__
    if module is None or module == str.__class__.__module__:
        return obj.__class__.__name__
    return module + '.' + obj.__class__.__name__
```

Example:

```
try:
    # <do something with sqlalchemy that angers the database>
except sqlalchemy.exc.SQLAlchemyError as e:
    print(get_full_class_name(e))

# sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError
```

Answer (score 16):

You can print the exception using some formated strings:

Example:

```
try:
    #Code to execute
except Exception as err:
    print(f"{type(err).__name__} was raised: {err}")
```

Comment: It helped a lot.

Answer (score 11):

You can also use `sys.exc_info()`. `exc_info()` returns 3 values: type, value, traceback. On documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info

```
import sys

try:
    foo = bar
except Exception:
    exc_type, value, traceback = sys.exc_info()
    assert exc_type.__name__ == 'NameError'
    print "Failed with exception [%s]" % exc_type.__name__
```

Answer (score 6):

This works, but it seems like there must be an easier, more direct way?

```
try:
    foo = bar
except Exception as exception:
    assert repr(exception) == '''NameError("name 'bar' is not defined",)'''
    name = repr(exception).split('(')[0]
    assert name == 'NameError'
```

Comment: Replace `except Exception as exception` with the type of exception you'd like to catch, i.e. `except NameError as exception`.

Comment: I don't want to catch particular exceptions known in advance.  I want to catch *all* exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

When you say "name" this could mean a couple of things: it could mean only the "immediate" classname, or it could mean the fully qualified name. Usually the latter will be much more useful and less error-prone: I've come across more than one case of 2 or more types with same "immediate" classname but from different packages.

If you want to print or log the fully qualified name this is one of the simplest things to do:

```
try:
    do_something()
except BaseException as e:
    logger.error(f'whoops! {type(e)}: {e}')
    # or maybe
    print(f'whoops! {type(e)}: {e}', file=sys.stderr)
```

The fully qualified classname will then be printed out like this: "<class 'json.decoder.JSONDecodeError'>", and then be followed by the exception message. The OP says he wants "for example", to *print* a message, so `assert` statements as in the chosen answer don't seem to be called for.

[The answer by MrName](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59537072/595305) is also not irrelevant, and does make a sensible suggestion! if in the above you replaced `logger.error(...)` with `logger.exception('whoops!')` (NB a user message is a required param) you'd get your exception's fully qualified name logged, not to mention its message, and a stack trace for free.

PS as suggested by the name, `JSONDecodeError` in my example is an `Error`, not an `Exception` (it is a subclass of `ValueError`). Catching `BaseException` (the superclass of both `Error` and `Exception`) usually makes life easier when you're not fishing for a specific exception. The OP says he wants to catch "all" exceptions.

Answer (score -1):

The other answers here are great for exploration purposes, but if the primary goal is to log the exception (including the name of the exception), perhaps consider using [logging.exception](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.exception) instead of print?

Comment: are you answering the question?