# treating error as a "message" in my column(df)

Tags: python, pandas

I have the below df:

```
    JOB_Command Parent_path
0   /data/ingestao_gpdb_nextdm_rep/execucao/call_r...   /data/ingestao_gpdb_nextdm_rep/execucao/call_r...
1   /data/processos/current/ingestao/ciclico/BACEN...   /data/processos/current/ingestao/
2   /data/processos/current/ingestao/ciclico/BACEN...   /data/processos/current/ingestao/
3   /data/processos/current/ingestao/ciclico/BACEN...   /data/processos/current/ingestao/
4   /data/processos/current/ingestao/ciclico/BACEN...   /data/processos/current/ingestao/
5   /data/processos/current/ingestao/ciclico/Inges...   /data/processos/current/ingestao/
```

And I'm using this piece of code to get the last update of a folder\file.

```
def get_fourth_elem(file_path):
    """Helper function.

    Args:
        file_path: file path as a string.

    Returns:
        absolute path to the fourth element (or last one if shorter) as a Pathlib object.
    """
    file_path_length = len(file_path.strip("/").split("/"))
    file_path = Path(file_path)
    if file_path_length > 4:
        for _ in range(file_path_length - 4):
            file_path = Path(file_path.parent)
        return file_path
    else:
        return file_path

df_test["Last_Update"] = df_test["JOB_Command"].apply(
    lambda x: datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(
        get_fourth_elem(x).stat().st_mtime
    ).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%H:%S")
    if Path(x).exists()
    else np.nan
)
```

But, I'm getting an error when I'm trying to analyze paths that I don't have access, would be possible to treat this and print some form of message "permission denied" ?

here is the sample of the error I'm getting
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/data/processos/current/ingestao/ciclico/IngestionManager_2_0_EXP/sbin/call_ingestion_manager_ciclico_exp.sh'

I tried to add some ifs but, it didn't work, now I'm studying exception, but, couldnt fit yet.

the output shoub be this:

```
    JOB_Command Parent_path Last_Update
0   /data/ingestao_gpdb_nextdm_rep/execucao/call_r...   /data/ingestao_gpdb_nextdm_rep/execucao/call_r...   2022-09-26 11:30:00
1   /data/processos/current/ingestao/ciclico/BACEN...   /data/processos/current/ingestao/                   2022-09-20 19:20:00             
2   /data/processos/current/ingestao/ciclico/BACEN...   /data/processos/current/ingestao/                   2022-09-20 19:20:00
3   /data/processos/current/ingestao/ciclico/BACEN...   /data/processos/current/ingestao/                   2022-09-20 19:20:00
4   /data/processos/current/ingestao/ciclico/BACEN...   /data/processos/current/ingestao/                   2022-09-20 19:20:00
5   /data/processos/current/ingestao/ciclico/Inges...   /data/processos/current/ingestao/                   NaN
```

could you gus helpo me?

Comment: I am curious about which line exactly is raining the permission denied error ? We can try to introduce a try-except block there.

Comment: Hi @kgkmeekg, thanks for your reply..The error is happening at index 5, the "Last_Update" value is NaN due the permission denied error accessing the Job_Commad path

Answer (score 1):

How about this :
We introduce a new function that does the file operation. `try-except` block to be used here.

```
def new_function(x):
    return_value = ''

    try
        if Path(x).exists() 
            return_value = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(get_fourth_elem(x).stat().st_mtime).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%H:%S") 
        else 
            return_value = np.nan
            
    except PermissionError:
        return_value = "Permission Denied") 
    else:
        return_value = "An unknown error occurred."
    return return_value
```

And then we can change your lambda function to use the new function:

```
df_test["Last_Update"] = df_test["JOB_Command"].apply( lambda x: new_function(x))
```

[This](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html), [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#BaseException) and [this](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/exception-handling) might be helpful to look at. In case you are getting the unknown error, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18176602/4168707) might help you get the name of the exception.

**Note:** Since there is no reproducible code available the above snippet might need some debugging.

Comment: the thing is this, it's not about to print on the screen, it's about to "save" the column valeu as NaN, so, I need to "access" the path and if I don't have permition, record NaN as the column value

Comment: You are already doing this in the lambda function I assume.  if Path(x).exists() is what is causing you the error. How about we define another function with the try-except block and use that in your lambda instead of defining the whole function there ?

Comment: yes, agreed, could you do that? I'm new to python and still studying the things that I need to delivery

Comment: just tried your approach, it gave me the "permission denied" message in the Last_Update column for the sample I mentioned, but, it didnt give me the last update for any path found in the Job_Command(and I should have some there), could that be because of the dataype?

Comment: basically I had 3 Permission Denied and all the rest were "An unknown error occurred."

Comment: inside the if it gave me the dates I was expecting(didnt count)
inside the else it gave me "nan" values
in the except it gave 3 permission denied
in the last else it gavem me the An unknown error occurred

Comment: I am a bit confused. So did it work or not ? I suggest posting a reproducible code if you want more clarification.

Comment: not as it should, it worked for the sample I mentioned that I was getting the permission denied.
but, there are paths that I have rights to access, and it should give me the date and it give me the message An unknown error occurred

Comment: Maybe this will help ? https://stackoverflow.com/q/18176602/4168707

Comment: sure, I'll have a look, so far, thanks man...