# How to get a dot notation of a python module?

Tags: python

I am writing a custom django model field which has serialize and unserialize operations, on unserialize, I am using the [import_by_path](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.module_loading.import_by_path) to get the class and initialise an instance.

On the opposite, I need to serialize an instance to the database, in my case all I need to get the dot notation of the module.

What I am asking is, how I can, eg I have the datetime module

```
from datetime import datetime
```

how to output `datetime` in dot notation to string `"datetime.datetime"` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get fully qualified class name of an object in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020014/get-fully-qualified-class-name-of-an-object-in-python)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not entirely clear on what you're asking, but dot notation is equivalent to your above example in Python, for instance:

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime
```

is the same as

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime
```

I hope that makes sense, let me know if you have any more questions.

Here's a better example:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime
<module 'datetime' from '/path/to/python'>
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime
<type 'datetime.datetime'>
```

Edit: After seeing the clarification, this should be done with the python `inspect` module. Specifically, if you're trying to get the module that defines a particular class:

```
import inspect
import datetime

inspect.getmodule(datetime).__name__
```

or

```
def dot_notation(your_module):
    return your_module.__module__ + "." + your_module.__class__.__name__
```

in a more general way, you can get the module

Comment: Hi I have added the string quotes around the output, hope this makes more clear what I want to achieve

Comment: Hi I am not asking how to import modules, I am trying to get the dot notation representation of a module.

Comment: @JamesLin OOooh, I see. Updating now.

Comment: `>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.__module__+'.'+datetime.__class__.__name__
'datetime.type'` doesn't give me `'datetime.datetime'`

Comment: @JamesLin That's why I specific called in the input `your_module`, use the inspect module if it's a type or an object as in the first example.

Comment: `from datetime import datetime
>>> inspect.getmodule(datetime).__name__
'datetime'` but I am expecting to see `'datetime.datetime'`

Comment: @JamesLin Exactly, you just add that to the name of your module with a dot.

Answer (score 0):

```
import inspect

from datetime import datetime


inspect.getmro(datetime)[0]
```

That should return 'datetime.dateime'