# Get the full name of a nested class

Tags: python, class, python-3.x

Given a nested class `B`:

```
class A:
    class B:
        def __init__(self):
            pass

ab = A.B()
```

How can I get the full name of the class for `ab`? I'd expect a result like `A.B`.

Comment: Why are you nesting classes? What do you need that name for? What's the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: One of my strongest reason is that is show like good practice for modules. For example i have one class which is envelope for all module. I use it because python hasnt perfect solution for modules. 

second reason it is better decomposition of problem.

Comment: That's not a great reason; Python *does* have a solution for modules, and it's, err, modules. The file, or directory containing `__init__.py`, is the module. You don't have to wrap everything in classes, this isn't Java. Maybe you should have asked that question instead.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020014/get-fully-qualified-class-name-of-an-object-in-python

Comment: Yes, i know and i use `__init__.py`. I would like discuss about this with someone who has deep knowledge.

I decided for this wrapping solution few months ago. Now i am not able perfectly describe  my trouble which i had. Simply i dont remmber.

But I would have other question. What you see like good practice for using class nesting.

Thank you.

Comment: The good practice is: don't nest classes. There's almost always another, better way to do whatever you're doing.

Answer (score 10):

You could get the fully qualified name, [`__qualname__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#definition.__qualname__), of its [`__class__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#instance.__class__):

```
>>> ab.__class__.__qualname__
'A.B'
```

Preferably by using [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) (which calls `__class__` on the instance):

```
>>> type(ab).__qualname__
```