# Determine an object's package

Tags: python

Is there a way to reliably get an object's package name? I'm trying  to programmatically determine if a connector is from mysqldb, pyscopg2, cx_oracle, or pymssql. I had been using the `conn.__class__` and regular expression previously but then stumbled when MySQLdb broke the pattern.

psycopg2:  `<type 'psycopg2.extensions.connection'>`

oracle:  `<type 'cx_Oracle.Connection'>`

pymssql:  `<type 'pymssql.Connection'>`

mysqldb: `MySQLdb.connections.Connection`

I'm wondering if there's a builtin python method of finding a classes' package. Ideally, this would simply return `psycopg2`, `cx_Oracle`, `pymssql`, or `MySQLdb`

Yes, thank you, [Get fully qualified class name of an object in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020014/get-fully-qualified-class-name-of-an-object-in-python) was the first thing that came up when I searched also. psycopg2, cx_oracle, and pymssql all return `AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute '__module___'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020014/get-fully-qualified-class-name-of-an-object-in-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get fully qualified class name of an object in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020014/get-fully-qualified-class-name-of-an-object-in-python)

Comment: `AttributeError: 'psycopg2.extensions.connection' object has no attribute '__module__'`

Comment: Try using `obj.__class__.__module__`, the accepted answer is not correct.

Comment: Try `conn.__class__.__module__`

Answer (score 0):

Use `inspect.getmodule()`.

You may inspect the module's `__package__` after you get the module if it doesn't suffice.

Another option would be to get use `inspect.getfile()` and search for the known strings.

Comment: the inspect.getmodule(conn) returns None for all the connections I'm working with