# Check if object is an instance of a library

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I need to check whether an object is from the `sklearn` library. Basically, I need to check if a model belongs to a specific library so I can create a general pattern based on it's type.

I need to check that if I receive a `model` object that it belongs to the `sklearn` library.

For example,

```
if isinstance(model, sklearn):
    #do something
```

I would like to avoid try drilling down to checking types of specific models.

For example,

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.cluster import FeatureAgglomeration
if isinstance(model, sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression):
   #to something 

if isinstance(model, sklearn.cluster.FeatureAgglomeration):
   #to something
```

The above are acceptable models. However, `sklearn` has too many models and is constantly changing. I would just like to check if its from the `sklearn` library.

Comment: You can just check the output of `model.__module__` and see if starts with `sklearn`. Possible duplicate of [Get fully qualified class name of an object in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020014/get-fully-qualified-class-name-of-an-object-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use :

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.cluster import FeatureAgglomeration
```

the `sklearn` object is not imported, only `LinearRegression` and `FeatureAgglomeration` are, so you must use this :

```
if isinstance(model, LinearRegression):
   #to something 

if isinstance(model, FeatureAgglomeration):
   #to something
```

or import sklearn object

```
import sklearn
if isinstance(model, sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression):
   #to something 

if isinstance(model, sklearn.cluster.FeatureAgglomeration):
   #to something
```

Answer (score 6):

No ideal but u can use:

```
if "sklearn" in str(type(model)):
```