# Importing a class from saved reference

Tags: python, pickle

Given a python class imported in the current context, is there a way to save a serializable (picklable) reference to that class, which can be imported later on another python context?

e.g.

First save the reference. In this example `get_reference` and `import_reference` are the function I wish to implement.

```py
import pickle
from torch.optim import SGD

sgd = SGD()
# ... do work ...

opt_reference = get_reference(sgd.__class__)
with open('SGD_ref.pkl', 'wb') as fp:
    pickle.dump(opt_reference, fp)
```

Then to import the reference

```py
import pickle

with open('SGD.pkl', 'rb') as fp:
    opt_reference = pickle.load(fp)

SGD = import_reference(opt_reference)

sgd = SGD()
```

I do not wish to save the code or implementation of the SGD function itself, since it also imports several things on its own. I am assuming the module that I wish to save the reference of is similarly installed and imported to every python environment it is gonna be used in.

One simple approach I found is to use the function from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020014/get-fully-qualified-class-name-of-an-object-in-python) to get the path for the `get_reference` function and then for the `import reference` do `eval(f"import {opt_reference}")`. This seems too hacky and very unsafe (although I do not care about safety in this context).

Is there any better way of doing this?

Comment: Do you want to save the contents of the instance or the actual class as a usable python class?

Comment: Neither. I want to save an "importable" reference. That can be a string such as `torch.optim.SGD` but it can also be some sort of importlib spec. I am not sure what it should be, because the mechanism of importing it from the saved reference is not clear to me.