# How to log a Python 3 exception, but without its stack trace?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

When I want to log some specific Exception, but otherwise ignore it, I can do that like so:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

try:
    something_that_may_fail()
except NameError:
    logger.error("It failed with:", exc_info=True)
```

(This is in fact an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), as `something_that_may_fail` hasn't been defined, so the `try` block will raise `NameError` with message `name 'something_that_may_fail' is not defined`. )

This however will also log the stack trace:

```
It failed with:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
NameError: name 'something_that_may_fail' is not defined
```

Sometimes that isn't what I want: In some cases, I already know that exception type and exception message (together with my custom log message) will suffice, and don't want to expand the log with stack traces that don't tell me anything new. So I'd want a log entry that simply is

```
It failed with:
NameError: name 'something_that_may_fail' is not defined
```

I can achieve that by passing a 3-tuple as the `exc_info`, with the stack trace component replaced by `None`:

```
import logging
import sys

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

try:
    something_that_may_fail()
except NameError:
    exc_type, exc_value, _trace = sys.exc_info()
    logger.error("It failed with:", exc_info=(exc_type, exc_value, None))
```

But I'm not sure how reliable that is. ([The documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.debug) doesn't mention how the tuple may or may not deviate from one returned by `sys.exc_info()`.)

Examining the exception myself with

```
...
except NameError as e:
    ...
```

comes with its own problems:

- `f"{type(e)}"` gives string `<class 'NameError'>` instead of just string `NameError`

  - The proper solution to get the fully qualified type name, including packages/modules but without `builtin.` is rather  unwieldy and not something I'd want in exception handling code. See [the currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2020083/674064) to [Get fully qualified class name of an object in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2020014/674064).
- Can I rely on the message always being `e.args[0]`? (I might have uses for other exceptions (with more sub-types) than just `NameError`, which I've used here only as an example.)

So what is the proper way to log exception type and message without the stack trace? Is there a cleaner way than my make-the-trace-`None` hack above?

Comment: I may not fully understand the question, but how about this: `logger.error(f"It failed with: {e.__class__.__name__}: {e}")`

Comment: The internal structure of an exception is not standardized. You can't really assume much at all about an arbitrary exception, though if you are catching a specific *kind* of exception, you can make assumptions about exceptions of that specific type.

Comment: @tituszban `e.__class__.__name__` won't tell me the module the Exception is from. (Which might be important, e.g. if it comes from a third-party library.)

Comment: @chepner, I'm looking for a solution that will also work when I won't know all types of exceptions I might handle there, e.g. in an `except Exception:` or even `except:` block. (Yes, I know one usually shouldn't use those, especially not the latter.)

Comment: Like I said, exception structure isn't standardized. You *can't* handle an arbitrary exception without first seeing what type it is, then branching to specific code for that exception type when necessary.

Comment: Does that mean that there be some exceptions that `logger.error(..., exc_info=True)` or ``logger.error(..., exc_info=sys.exc_info())`` can't properly handle, either? @chepner

Comment: Instead of `e.__class__.__name__` you could use [`e.__class__.__qualname__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#definition.__qualname__), which contains the module as well.

Comment: @SvenEberth, That doesn't seem to be the case. Try `import requests; print(requests.Timeout.__qualname__)`. Output on Python 3.7.10 is only `Timeout`. Or with only Python standard library: `import json; print(json.JSONDecodeError.__qualname__)` which gives just `JSONDecodeError`.

Comment: (`__qualname__` is still useful for nested classes, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/2020083/674064)

Comment: @das-g Oh, I should have had a look at the according [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3155/#excluding-the-module-name) before... My mistake, sorry. Then you must also use `__module__` (like in the answer your linked).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`traceback.format_exception_only`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html#traceback.format_exception_only) can be used for that:

```
import logging
import sys
import traceback

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

try:
    something_that_may_fail()
except NameError:
    exc_type, exc_value, _trace = sys.exc_info()
    exc_desc_lines = traceback.format_exception_only(exc_type, exc_value)
    exc_desc = ''.join(exc_desc_lines).rstrip()
    logger.error(f"It failed with:\n{exc_desc}")
```

or without `sys`:

```
import logging
import traceback

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

try:
    something_that_may_fail()
except NameError as e:
    exc_desc_lines = traceback.format_exception_only(type(e), e)
    exc_desc = ''.join(exc_desc_lines).rstrip()
    logger.error(f"It failed with:\n{exc_desc}")
```

(Found this by looking [how the `logging` module actually extracts and formats information from `exc_info`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a13edfb857793f0f92a4fef3919f215e008df5c5/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L667-L671). There [`traceback.print_exception` is being used](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a13edfb857793f0f92a4fef3919f215e008df5c5/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L621), so I looked what else is available in the `traceback` module.)

Comment: I like the latter in a oneliner: `''.join(traceback.format_exception_only(type(e), e)).rstrip()`. I dislike that this is necessary though, why does the `Exception` class not provide this obvious value/method to retrieve this!? There is no other language which I am aware of  where this is not directly accessible.