# How to check where a python method is defined?

Tags: python

I can call a function in python. And it is not a built-in.

Is there a way to check in which module or class this method is defined?

Comment: Similar : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020014/get-fully-qualified-class-name-of-an-object-in-python

Answer (score -1):

Just found it. Seems the [inspect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) module can do the trick.

```
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.getmodule(xxx)
```